# PHP money_format

Tags: php, string, locale, string-formatting, money-format

I'm using on `money_format` with the first parameter being `'%n'` to include the dollar sign, and I have the locale set to `en_US` but it still doesn't include it. Why?

Comment: Are you using a Debian based system? say Ubuntu.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [PHP.net comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#86039):

> If money_format doesn't seem to be
>   working properly, make sure you are
>   defining a valid locale.  For example,
>   on Debian, 'en_US' is not a valid
>   locale - you need 'en_US.UTF-8' or
>   'en_US.ISO-8559-1'.
>
> This was frustrating me for a while. 
>   Debian has a list of valid locales at
>   /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED; find yours
>   there if it's not working properly.

Comment: That sounds like it'll fix it. It's running on a Ubuntu server, and thats why the servers at work, work. They're running redhat. Thanks! I'll try it when i get home.

Comment: That's a pretty interesting little caveat to the php Debian installs out there.

Comment: This just saved me so much time of debugging. If you have a debian/ubuntu you need to check that you are using the valid locale.

Comment: To see the list of valid locales on the server, we can run this command `locale -a`. It's still possible that we can use `<?php echo shell_exec('locale -a')` to find this list if we do not have terminal access to the server.