# PHP money_format() -- No comma delimiter?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP money_format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158517/php-money-format)

Why does this:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', 1234.56);
```

Output the value I gave it (1234.56)?
I'm using Linux with basic LAMP installation.

Expected output is "1,234.56"

EDIT:
`locale -a` returns the following list:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
zh_CN.utf8
zh_SG.utf8
```

That's annoying. en_US.utf8 works just fine!

Comment: `var_dump(setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US'));` return false?

Comment: Yep, false. boolean false

1234.56

Comment: Then there is no en_US locale installed on server

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fba0ec1e5e9507c7ce7d576d40c32eb65e739d89

Comment: `locale -a` shows `en_US.utf8`, when I use that, I get the following output (see updated question)

Comment: this outputs USD 1,234.56  for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess someone thought it would be funny to name it `en_US.utf8` instead of `en_US`.

Those jerks!

Comment: Those 'jerks' knows that `en_US.utf8` != `en_US` and build software that runs on bilions of servers, so a little respect please.

Comment: It's a joke, calm down dude.

Comment: This one actually caught me as well. I'm sure there is a good reason upstream not to symlink. Should have checked the return value on set_locale() sooner i guess. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I think the first example at http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php is incorrect.